# Sql Server ce issues in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a project in Windows phone 7.5 and for storing data I'm using Sql Server ce 3.5  which is not shown in server explorer of visual studio 2012.
Is there any method by which i can use database connectivity in my windows phone 7.5 application.

Comment: Use the SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in, it works with 3.5 in VS 2012

Comment: @ErikEJ - In server explorer option in visual studio 2012, there are no option for SQL server ce 3.5, only Sql server 4.0 is showing.

Comment: But the Toolbox supports 3.5...

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately SQL sever CE 3.5 is not supported in visual studio 2012.

Comment: thanx, but can you suggest any alternative for this.